# Is it possible to generate an english translation file based on default translations used in a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4 docs state the following:

> For applications with heavy translation requirements, defining every
>   string with a "short key" can become quickly confusing when
>   referencing them in your views. For this reason, Laravel also provides
>   support for defining translation strings using the "default"
>   translation of the string as the key.

So if I use `echo __('I love programming.');` and there is no matching translation, it will return 'I love programming.'. So what happens down the line when I decide to add translations? Can Laravel extract all the language phrases I've used and put them into a translation file somewhere? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but for all other Googlers out there, see this package: https://github.com/kkomelin/laravel-translatable-string-exporter

After installing it allows you to do what OP asked: Extract the translations to a `.json` file based on files you can specify.

For example:

```
$ php artisan translatable:export en

Translatable strings have been extracted and written to the en.json file.
```

Answer (score -1):

When you decide to add translation, you'll have to provide your user a way to  `select` the desired language. At this point, you'll do something like `App::setLocale('whatever')` or `App::setLocale('pt-BR');`. Now, Laravel will go to your `resources/lang/` folder and look for a `whatever.json` or `pt-BR.json`, where you'll store a file like this:

pt-BR.json

```
{
    'I love programming': 'Eu amo programar.'
}
```

whatever.json

```
{
    'I love programming': 'Equivalent text that you want to be displayed.'
}
```

Basically, the `__()` function will look for the language defined in the current request (see in your app.php the available locale and fallback_locale) and look for a json with a translation to that. If nothing is found, it will fallback to the fallback locale. If that file also doesn't exist, it will just display the given string.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. If I want to create a new translation, I need to know the list of english phrases to provide to a translator. I am asking how to compile a list of english translations used throughout my view files.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower I don't know if that's possible. But the whole point of having this sort of translation system is so a translator can just see a message in a screen and translate it in a JSON format. You may try to overwrite the `__()` function and save the given key into a file, but that would require someone to make sure to go through every screen/function call of the system so the file would be complete.